# Binary tree that stores partial sums: Name and existing implementations

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree, montecarlo

Consider a sequence of *n* positive real numbers, (*a<sub>i</sub>*), and its partial sum sequence, (*s<sub>i</sub>*). Given a number *x* ∊ (0, *s<sub>n</sub>*], we have to find *i* such that *s*<sub>*i*−1</sub> < *x* ≤ *s<sub>i</sub>*. Also we want to be able to change one of the *a<sub>i</sub>*’s without having to update all partial sums. Both can be done in O(log *n*) time by using a binary tree with the *a<sub>i</sub>*’s as leaf node values, and the values of the non-leaf nodes being the sum of the values of the respective children. If *n* is known and fixed, the tree doesn’t have to be self-balancing and can be stored efficiently in a linear array. Furthermore, if *n* is a power of two, only 2 *n* − 1 array elements are required. See Blue et al., Phys. Rev. E **51** (1995), pp. R867–R868 for an application. Given the genericity of the problem and the simplicity of the solution, I wonder whether this data structure has a specific name and whether there are existing implementations (preferably in C++). I’ve already implemented it myself, but writing data structures from scratch always seems like reinventing the wheel to me—I’d be surprised if nobody had done it before.

Answer (score 5):

This is known as a [finger tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_tree) in functional programming but apparently there are implementations in imperative languages. In the articles there is a link to a [blog post](http://dnovatchev.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!44B0A32C2CCF7488!582.entry) explaining an implementation of this data structure in C# which could be useful to you.

Answer (score 4):

[Fenwick tree](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Fenwick_tree) (aka Binary indexed tree) is a data structure that maintains a sequence of elements, and is able to compute cumulative sum of any range of consecutive elements in O(logn) time. Changing value of any single element needs O(logn) time as well.